# Jacobi-Trudi Identity - Enumerative Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

The Jacobi-Trudi Identity states that:

Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1, \ldots ,\lambda_n)$ and $\mu=(\mu_1, \ldots ,\mu_n)\subseteq \lambda$.

Then, $s_{\lambda/\mu} = \det(h_{\lambda_i -\mu_j -i+j})^n_{i,j=1}$

where $h_0=1$ and $h_k=0$ for all $k<0$.

Is this theorem necessarily true? Can someone prove that the identity is indeed equal?

Comment: I think I've seen this equation used as the definition of the skew Schur function $s_{\lambda/\mu}$. Which of the many (equivalent) definitions are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  It's simply just a pure application of theorem 2.7.1 stated in *Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. 1.* ([Link here](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf))

> Take $\alpha_j=\lambda_j+n-j$, $\beta_i=\mu_i+n-i$, $\gamma\to\infty$.